# how to plot geom_area() in ggplot in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe on multiple columns from land use. I would like to make chart in ggplot using geom_area() with areas piled up from years.

my exemple data-frame:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

n<-c(1,1,1,1,1)
year<-c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009)
veg<-c(1,2,3,2.3,4.1)
wet<-c(2,2.3,1.9,2.5,2.2)
dry<-c(5,5.1,6.9,4.3,5.3)
grass<-c(10,11,12,13,9.7)

data_land<-data.frame(n, year, veg, wet, dry, grass)
```

i hope similar to this

[image]

UPDATE:

I edited (removed code ggplot) the code because error in sintaxes.

Comment: I guess you can try `geom_area(position="fill")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help to reshape the data into the longer format that ggplot2 works with best:

```
data_land %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(n:year)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, fill = name)) +
  geom_area(position = "fill")
```

[image]

Or, if you want raw amounts, instead of having it normalized to 100% like your example goal, you can remove `position = "fill"` from the `geom_area` line:

[image]

Comment: Because the Y axis does not have the values of veg, wet, dry, grass?

Comment: This looks to me like the example you pointed to, an area chart showing the proportions out of 100%. Can you please explain more what you're looking for and point out anything specific that's different? If you want raw amounts, remove `position = "fill"`.